# Wordpress searchform

Tags: wordpress, search

I have to make a new website with an advanced search form in php, but I don't know how to find it. An example: http://www.neckermann.be (like the box in the middle).
Is there some kind of a plugin in wordpress?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38361/advanced-search-form-with-filters-for-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this plugin [Travel Search](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/travel-search/)